# Ionic4/Angular 8 - HTML video tag not playing base64 string

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

for the love of me, I cannot figure out why this is happening. 
when I send the message with the base64 I can see the video and it plays fine, however, when I receive a base64 I cannot see the video. It just shows a broken link icon in the middle.

html section:

```html
<video controls preload="auto" class="video-style">
  <source type="video/mp4" [src]="(message.data.base64) | safe" />
</video>
```

Safe Pipe

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe',
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  private sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
  }
  transform(value: string): SafeUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
  }
}
```

and then the message.data.base64 === `"data:video/mp4;charset=utf-8;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA…b2z7S/NR4vPp0+njq+gEgAr7mfb3/JQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="`
I tried with both the charset included and excluded with no difference. I need the Dom Sanatizer or else Angular will sanatize it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated but `this.sanitizer = sanitizer;` is not required inside the constructor. Injecting it is enough to refer it using `this`. Try without that statement.

Comment: @MichaelD our linter doesn't like declaring within the constructor so I have to do it like this.